# Add existing project to solution under visualvsn

Tags: svn, version-control, visualsvn

We are changing from SourceSafe 2005 to visual svn.

How can an exisiting project be added to a solution

Example:

- I create solution1 with 3 projects and add to /trunk
- I create solution2 with 1 project and add to /trunk

In solution1 I add existing project from solution2, but I cannot add to subversion. I get "out of working copy, use the VisualSVN->Set Working Copy root menu"

In SourceSafe2005 it would just link, what is the procedure for VisualSVN? Branch?

Regards

_Eric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that solution1 is a different working copy than solution2. They're both part of the same repository though (that's what I'd strongly recommend if you want to do any sort of useful branching and tagging).

VisualSvn doesn't allow you to have projects in multiple working copies, because Subversion cannot commit multiple working copies atomically (ie fully succeeding or fully failing, and resulting in a single revision number).

There are a few options around this:

- you can add an [svn:externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn-book.html#svn.advanced.externals) definition in the working copy for solution1. This makes the project from solution2 part of the working copy for solution1.
- you can use [AnkhSVN](http://ankhsvn.net), a free tool that *does* allow you to use/commit multiple working copies. You will get a dialog asking you wether to use the same log message for both commits, or to only commit to one working copy (leaving the other files uncommitted so you can enter a different log message).